# CSS - how do I align these elements?

Tags: css

please have a look at [this page](http://www.caraudiostyle.gr/test_header.php) and tell me what needs to be changed in order to have the search box float next to the "KissMyBass" image and have a small margin from the cart box on top. I've tried all sorts of float & clear combinations but without luck. Perhaps its a positioning thing but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this into your css file:

```
#search_block_top { margin-top: -40px;}
```

Make sure you don't override this property later (you have a `margin:10px` setted somewhere.).

Comment: Thanks. It didnt occur to me to use a negative value, very handy!

Answer (score 1):

```
div#search_block_top {
    background: url("../images/bg_search.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    height: 26px;
    margin: -40px 9px 0 0;
    right: 210px;
    top: 55px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your html  structure, right now you have

```
<div>shopping cart</div>
<div>image</div>
<div>search</div>
```

and all of them have `float: right`. How about structure like

```
<div>
  <div>shopping cart></div>
  <div>search</div>
</div>
<div>image</div>
```

Without changing CSS you should get more or less what you are looking for.

UPDATE: sorry if I missunderstood what you are doing, this `clear: right;` suggested me that you would like to put this div next to image on its right side but below shopping cart:)

Answer (score 0):

I have given the **parent** to div to your **right child div's** so now you have to just add this mentioned below code in your code it will work smoothly:-

**Code:-**

```
<div style="float:right; width:460px; border:2px solid yellow;">
<div id="phoneorders" style="width: 244px; float: left;"> <img width="166" height="57" src="images/phonesupport.png"> <br>
        <img width="170" height="46" src="images/kissmybass.png"> </div>
<div id="shopping_cart"><a target="_self" class="bluelink" href="#">Shopping cart</a><br> (0)  €</div>


        <div id="search_block_top">
                <form method="post" action="#" id="searchbox">
                  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="search_query ac_input" id="search_query_top" name="search_query" value="" onfocus="if(this.value=='')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='';">
                  <a href="#"></a>
                  <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="position">
                  <input type="hidden" name="orderway" value="desc">
                </form>
              </div>
        </div>
```